# How to prevent a kernel module from loading?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I want to write a module for a usb mouse, so I need to disable the `usbhid` driver from loading. The thing is it loads again when I connect the mouse. So, how can I disable permanently a module from loading if nothing depends on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf** and put the following line there:

```
blacklist usbhid
```

Upon reboot the module will be blacklisted from automatic loading.